# Solução para <select> com muitas opções

Tags: php, html

Qual a melhor solução para fazer o `<select>` deixar tal resultado selecionado em um `<select>` com muitas opções ?

Eu uso IF nesssa situação com poucas opções, mas fica inviavel para um  muito grande...

segue código de exemplo:

```
<select class="alterarperfilNomeInput2" name="sexo">
<?php 
if ($row[sexo] == "Masculino")
{
echo "<option value=\"Masculino\" selected>Masculino</option>
<option value=\"Feminino\">Feminino</option>";
}
else
{
echo "<option value=\"Masculino\">Masculino</option>
<option value=\"Feminino\" selected>Feminino</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

---

segue tambem código do select que preciso deixar uma opção selecionada apenas de acordo com o BD...

```
<select name="dia" class="alterarperfilNomeInput2A">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nessas situações você pode utilizar o operador ternário `?:`, diretamente no `echo`, assim:

```
<select class="alterarperfilNomeInput2" name="sexo">
<option value="Masculino"<?php echo ($row[sexo] == "Masculino" ? ' selected':'') ?>>Masculino</option>
<option value="Feminino"<?php echo ($row[sexo] == "Feminino" ? ' selected':'') ?>>Feminino</option>
</select>
```

Para o dia use um `for`, assim:

```
<select name="dia" class="alterarperfilNomeInput2A">
<?php
for($i = 1;$i<=31;$i++) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.($row[dia] == $i ? ' selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>'."\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes sempre fazer uma chamada ajax e obter o valor que tens guardado na base de dados (consegues fazer isso?). A partir daí, basta colocares uma função no `document ready` da página:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var opcao = "5"; //exemplo de um valor do dia
    $('[name=dia]').val(opcao);
});
```

Link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6vusa4m/2/)

Com este exemplo vai funcionar para qualquer tipo de `select` que possas ter. Caso apareça um que não seja com os dias do mês (o value é um inteiro) e seja com marcas de automóvel ou assim (o value é string) terás problemas...

Answer (score 2):

Com esta função fica com a liberdade de utilizar numeros ou letras e também pode colocar o valor diferente do texto nas suas opções para select.

```
$dias = range(1,31);//array 1 a 31
$cont = 5;
select($dias,$cont);

$gender = array("masculino"=>"homem", "feminino"=>"mulher");
$gcont = "masculino";
select($gender,$gcont);

function select(array $options, $controler){
    $select_options = NULL;
    foreach ($options as $key=>$value) {
        $selec = ($key == $controler) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
        $select_options .= "<option value='$key' $selec>$value</option>";
    }  
    return $select_options;
}
```